When a current passes through the secondary of an ideal transformer, KVL is violated in th primary?
When an ideal transformer is on the no load condition, the primary circuit is just a normal AC source connected to an inductor. In other words, the voltage across the inductors equals the source voltage leading the current by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ phase angle. The current set up creates in turns a mmf that set up the flux which ought to remain the same and it does. When a load is connected to the secondary, a resistor for example, a current originates that sets up an opposite mmf that drives the flux in the opposite direction reducing therefore the induced emf in the primary. My question is, isn't that a violation of KVL? I mean the induced emf is now less than the source!

For starters, I usually hate using anything to do with Kirchhoff in analysis, and I'd much rather turn to Faraday to get the job done.
However, to answer your question, KVL is not violated. At any given point the primary current will adjust itself to ensure that the sum of the induced EMF and the voltage drop across the primary winding impedance equals the source voltage.
We know the primary winding sees the source voltage which is equal to the sum of the induced EMF and the voltage drop. When the second current creates an opposing flux, the induced EMF might be slightly less than the source voltage, but the additional current drawn from the source will compensate for this.
You can't see this quite too well with Kirchhoff's laws, because it has no way of telling you how flux changes. Trust Faraday!

First, let me point out that the induced emf leads to the voltage drop across the inductor so they are really referring to the same thing up to a sign. Now, how the increased primary current would compensate for the decrease in the induced emf? The transformer is ideal so no resistance is assumed to be in the primary meaning that the primary current doesn't contribute to the voltage drop. Only the inductor is there to do the job!

@Jack induced EMF is minus voltage only in ideal inductor with no resistance, and no other EMFs present. And even if the inductor is ideal, if there are additional extraneous EMFs acting on current in the inductor, then self-induced EMF in the inductor no longer equals minus the voltage. This can be seen from Kirchhoff's second circuital law, see my answer.


When an ideal transformer is on the no load condition, the primary circuit is just a normal AC source connected to an inductor. In other words, the voltage across the inductors equals the source voltage leading the current by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ phase angle.

To my surprise, ideal transformer is something different than I expected. Not only are all ohmic resistances and hysteresis losses zero as I thought, but also, permeability of the core is assumed infinite, so both primary alone and secondary alone have infinite impedance. So if secondary is disconnected, current flowing in the primary is zero.
This is quite unrealistic description of what happens with disconnected secondary. Below, by "ideal transformer" I will mean a more realistic model of transformer, where Joule losses in the windings and hysteretic losses in the medium are zero, but permeability of the medium is only finite, so the primary current has a non-zero amplitude even when secondary is disconnected.
Yes, voltage on the primary winding equals voltage on the source, and this is true regardless of whether the transformer is ideal or not.
For ideal transformer with disconnected secondary (no losses in the winding and core), the phase angle is $\pi/2$.

When a load is connected to the secondary, a resistor for example, a current originates that sets up an opposite mmf that drives the flux in the opposite direction reducing therefore the induced emf in the primary. My question is, isn't that a violation of KVL? I mean the induced emf is now less than the source!

No, because KVL does not say anything about induced EMFs.
When the secondary is loaded so it has current that affects the core and the primary, voltage on the primary is (assuming a very hard source) almost unchanged, while amplitude of the sum of self-induced and core-induced EMF in the primary decreases, as you point out. Thus voltage on the primary no longer has the same magnitude as that part of induced EMF in the primary. This can only be understood if we realize that in KVL and in AC circuit theory, voltage is not the same thing as EMF. Below is an explanation.
Voltage on a circuit element is drop of electric potential in the positive direction chosen. This can be expressed as line integral of the conservative part of electric field, from one terminal to the other:
$$
V = \int_{\mathbf {x}_0}^{\mathbf x}\mathbf E_c \cdot d\mathbf{x}.
$$
Induced EMF is integral of the induced electric field, which is a non-conservative field:
$$
\mathscr{E}_{net} = \int_{\mathbf x_0}^{\mathbf x}\mathbf E_i \cdot d\mathbf x.
$$
Induced EMF thus depends on the path chosen. In an inductor or a transformer primary, the path of interest is the path of the current, so it starts at one terminal of the winding, goes inside the wire, following all its turns, and ends up at the other terminal. If resistance is zero, on any winding $\mathscr{E}_{net} = -V$. But if $\mathscr{E}_{net}$ consists of several different emfs due to different sources, any one of them need not equal $-V$, only their sum has to.
KVL: Sum of potential drops (decrease of electric potential in the chosen positive direction of circulation) on all elements in a closed path equals zero:
$$
\sum_k V_k = 0.
$$
Note that there is no mention of induced EMF here. For the primary circuit, we have
$$
V_{source} + V_{primary} = 0
$$
and thus voltage on primary $V_{primary} = -V_{source}$ (so $V_{source}$ here is negative). This holds generally, it does not matter whether the secondary is loaded or not. Load on the secondary may cause surge of current and decrease of amplitude of $V_{source}$, but even then, the amplitudes of voltages are the same. This is so, of course, because the two terminal points are the same, whether we calculate voltage on the source, or voltage on the primary winding.
Kirchhoff's second circuital law: Sum of all EMF's acting in a closed path equals sum of all terms $R_kI_k$ corresponding to all resistive elements in the path ($R_k$ is ohmic resistance of the element):
$$
\sum_m \mathscr{E}_m = \sum_k R_kI_k.
$$
Let $\mathscr{E}_{a,b}$ be the net EMF due to source $a$ acting on current in the path element (closed or unclosed) $b$. Let the label "primary" or "1" refer to just the primary winding.
If we have ideal source and ideal transformer with no resistance anywhere, the above law implies, for sum of all EMF's in the primary,
$$
\sum_m \mathscr{E}_m = 0.
$$
Let's denote all present EMFs in the primary circuit due to all sources: we have $\mathscr{E}_{source,source}$ that is the driving EMF that drives current in the source; $\mathscr{E}_{1,1}$ that is the self-induced EMF in the primary; $\mathscr{E}_{core,1}$ that is the induced EMF in the primary due to the core; $\mathscr{E}_{2,1}$ that is the induced EMF in the primary due to changes of current in the secondary. So we have
$$
\mathscr{E}_{source,source} + \mathscr{E}_{1,1} + \mathscr{E}_{core,1} + \mathscr{E}_{2,1} = 0.
$$
If the secondary is open (unloaded), the last term vanishes, and we can say net induced EMF in the primary equals minus the source EMF:
$$
\mathscr{E}_{1,1} + \mathscr{E}_{core,1} = - \mathscr{E}_{source}.
$$
If secondary is closed (loaded), we have
$$
\mathscr{E}_{1,1} + \mathscr{E}_{core,1} + \mathscr{E}_{2,1}= - \mathscr{E}_{source}.
$$
Again, we can say net induced EMF equals minus the source EMF, but now, the net induced EMF includes the effect of the secondary.


When a load is connected to the secondary, a resistor for example, a current originates that sets up an opposite mmf that drives the flux in the opposite direction reducing therefore the induced emf in the primary. My question is, isn't that a violation of KVL?

No. KVL tells you that the sum of voltage drops around a loop is zero. It doesn't tell you anything about what should be the voltage across any individual branch, so nothing you learn about what affects the voltage across a branch can contradict KVL.
You should notice that the equivalent circuit model of a transformer,

(image source) has the magnetizing inductance (Lm) and core loss (Rc) elements in parallel with the primary of the ideal transformer. These elements are necessary to model the inductor in open-secondary condition (because otherwise primary current would be exactly 0 with an open secondary). But because they're in parallel with the primary, you can't model this circuit with a single KVL equation.

I mean the induced emf is now less than the source!

It isn't. It just rebalances how much current is required to achieve the same emf and how much is due to the magnetizing inductance vs the secondary current being reflected through the ideal transformer.
It's like if I have a balanced see-saw and I put more weight on one side while somebody else controls the weight on the far side. Even though I don't know what the other person did, if the see-saw remains balanced I can infer that they added more weight on their side, rather than that newton's law of equal and opposite forces suddenly became invalid.

However, I was talking about the ideal transformer while what you posted up there is the equivalent circuit of the real one. In addition, in the ideal transformer on the no load condition, the primary current won't be zero even with the secondary circuit open.

@Jack you are totally misunderstanding: This answer is trying to tell you that your naïve treatment of transformers is unphysical because "These elements are necessary to model the inductor in open-secondary condition". Taking idealised limits of physical stuff has to be done in a way that protects the important physical properties.

@naturallyInconsistent I haven't invented the naive model, it's out there in any textbook. However, I can't see what physical properties you're referring to that are gonna be harmed in the ideal transformer model?

@Jack, about "in the ideal transformer on the no load condition, the primary current won't be zero even with the secondary circuit open.", that's not true. The ideal transformer model has $I_P=I_S/N$ where $N$ is the turns ratio. If $I_S$ is 0 then $I_P$ is also 0 in the ideal transformer. If you're using a different model as the "ideal transformer model", you should share that in your question post.

@Photon current in the primary won't be zero when secondary is disconnected. The transformer primary circuit then behaves as a circuit with AC source acting on an inductor with a core. The relation between the primary and secondary current you mention does not hold then.

@JánLalinský, okay, but how is that behavior captured in the ideal transformer model? Only by including the magnetization inductance.

I'm not sure why you think additional inductor $L_M$ is needed in the scheme. The primary winding with core (and modified self-inductance) is already there in the scheme. $L_m$ is parallel to $L$, so it is eliminable and the result with single inductor is simpler.

@JánLalinský, have a look at the "Ideal Transformer Equations" sidebar on the Wikipedia article Transformer. We have $I_p V_p = I_s V_s$. If $I_s$ is 0, and $V_p$ and $V_s$ aren't 0, then $I_p$ must be 0. This model does not have the behavior you described. You might have a different model in mind when you say "ideal transformer model", but many people mean the one described on Wikipedia, and that "ideal transformer model" does not pass any current through the primary when the secondary is not loaded.

See eq. 4 in the sidebar - that is true only if the secondary is closed(loaded). It is not true when secondary is disconnected. But you are right that for the usual definition of ideal transformer, when secondary is disconnected, effective impedance of the primary winding terminals is infinite, and thus both currents are then zero. What I meant by ideal, and I suspect OP did as well, is a transformer made of ideal inductors with finite self-inductance and a lossless core with finite permeability.

So now I get why there is additional LM in the scheme for realistic transformer primary - the primary terminals have to have finite impedance in case secondary is disconnected, and the ideal part with core has infinite impedance, so the primary terminals have to be bridged by something realistic with finite impedance, such finite $L_M$. Thanks.
